# Material HTTP table example throws Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor in local environment

Tags: angular, http, angular-material, paginator

I am trying to create a table which is filled with HTTP requests therefore I started with the example provided in the documentation of angular material for an `HTTP table`:

https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

https://stackblitz.com/angular/rkmqrvxvjlk?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-http-example.ts

When I execute it in the website it works. But when I add it to a component in my local environment  I get this exceptions:

> Property 'exampleDatabase' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
> Property 'filteredAndPagedIssues' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
> Property 'paginator' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
> Property 'sort' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

I have tried workarounds of adding `?` or `!` after the variable but then it still won't work. I will not see the exception but it will crash on runtime with:

> ERROR TypeError: this.sort is undefined.

I have not done any change to the code more than changing the name of the component. Other than that I just coppied the HTML and the css together with the .ts content and imports:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to include the `MatSortModule`.

Don't forget it import it in your 'app.modules.ts'

```
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
...
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        MatSortModule
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```